# C : Processing the columns of a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM_ROWS 3
#define NUM_COLS 5

int main(void){ 

int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS],(*p)[NUM_COLS], i;

for (p = &a[0],i=0; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++,i++){
(*p)[i]=i;
}
printf("The value of a[0][0] is %d\n",a[0][0]); // I want 0
printf("The value of a[0][1] is %d\n",a[0][1]); // 1
printf("The value of a[0][2] is %d\n",a[0][2]); // 2
printf("The value of a[0][3] is %d\n",a[0][3]); // 3
printf("The value of a[0][4] is %d\n",a[0][4]); // 4

return 0;
}
```

Hi guys I'm a C novice, and I am trying to understand processing the columns of a 2D array.

I wanted output of 0,1,2,3,4 from row 0's columns but I had these results

```
The value of a[0][0] is 0
The value of a[0][1] is 0
The value of a[0][2] is 1
The value of a[0][3] is 0
The value of a[0][4] is -1
```

I tried to find what was wrong, but I failed to....

I will be grateful if someone explains what is wrong with my codes..

Comment: Try initializing the array with `int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] = {{0}};`, and after the loop, print the entire array to see what the loop did.

Comment: I did, but I only got 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: That's not the whole array. The whole array has 15 entries.

Comment: I posted another code would you see the answer below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++){
for(i=0;i<NUM_COLS;i++){
    (*p)[i]=i;
    printf("%d\n",(*p)[i]); 
// I got 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
}
}
```

Should I write nested loop to print out all elements of 2D?

Is there a way to print out using 1 loop with processing columns of 2D array?

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment in the loop is initializing the leading diagonal:

```
(*p)[i] = i;
```

To illustrate, here's an adaptation of your code that prints the whole matrix (and initializes it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 3
#define NUM_COLS 5

int main(void)
{
    int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], (*p)[NUM_COLS], i;

    /* Set all elements to -1 assuming 2's complement */
    memset(a, 0xFF, sizeof(a));

    for (p = &a[0], i = 0; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++, i++)
    {
        (*p)[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++)
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
  0 -1 -1 -1 -1
 -1  1 -1 -1 -1
 -1 -1  2 -1 -1
```

Notice that the three elements on the leading diagonal are set to 0, 1, 2 and the rest are -1 as set by `memset()`.

If you want to initialize the first row, then you simply use:

```
 int (*p)[NUM_COLS] = &a[0];
 for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++)
     (*p)[i] = i;
```

Or, more simply still, forget about `p` and use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++)
    a[0][i] = i;
```

If you want to initialize column 0, you need:

```
(*p)[0] = i;
```

Or, again, more simply, forget about `p` and use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
    a[0][i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write your `for` loop like this (based on you captions)
for the first row.

```
for (p = &a[0], i=0; i < NUM_COLS; i++){
    (*p)[i] = i;
}
```

Here increasing the pointer `p` doesn't help for it will be incremented by a value of `NUM_COLS` every time due to pointer arithmetic.

Here is a second possible answer if you want to write and read the whole matrix within a single for loop

```
for (p = &a[0], i = 0; i < NUM_COLS * NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    (*p)[i] = i;
}
```

Or the better solution would be to use two for loops as

```
for (p = &a[0], i = 0; p < &a[NUM_ROWS] ; p ++) {
    int k = 0; //for the column count
    for(;k < NUM_COLS; i++, k++) {
        (*p)[k] = i;
    }
}
```

Thanks for asking :)

Comment: If you want to parse a 2-D matrix fully and not just the first row, kindly ask in comments I will edit my answer to answer that too :)